# Удалить пункт меню

Tags: wordpress, menu

Как удалить пункт меню All Items в админке.
[image: указано стрелкой]

Comment: [remove_menu_page()](https://wp-kama.com/function/remove_menu_page)

Comment: Любым плагином для кастомизации меню/админки